# Setting up AWS Global Accelerator between two hosted zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

We are trying to setup AWS Global Accelerator for handling traffic outside of the US.

The setup seems simple enough and within the same hosted zone where the ALB is it works.  but when I create an A record in a different hosted zone and try to point it to the same GA static IPs it does not work.

I can traceroute to it but not access any of the endpoints through the ALB.

**Global Accelerator** (GA)

- IP1
- IP2
- Configured for ALB in Hosted Zone 1

**Hosted Zone 1 - aaa.example.com**

- ALB
- A-record to GA - works
- A-record to ALB - works

**Hosted Zone 2 - bbb.example.net**

- A-record to GA - does not work (traceroute does)

All of theses are backed by AWS managed SSL certificates too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out it was because the SSL listeners for the certs were not added to the ALB.  Once that was done it was fine.